# Compile *.cpp and *.c with Automake

Tags: c++, linker-errors, automake

Structure:

```
-myProject
    -Makefile.am
    -configure.ac
    -src
        -Makefile.am
        -main.c
        -test.c
        -test.h
```

When I try to compile, I've got the error Undefinded reference to a function from test.c.

Makefile.am:

```
   AUTOMAKE_OPTIONS = foreign
   SUBDIRS=src
```

src/Makefile.am:

```
   bin_PROGRAMS = TEST
   AM_CXXFLAGS =-Wall -Wno-psabi -w -pthread -I/usr/local/include
   AM_CFLAGS =-Wall -w
   #Sources
   TEST_SOURCES = test.c main.cpp
   TEST_LDADD = @LDFLAGS@ -lmosquitto
   TEST_LDFLAGS =-lmosquitto
```

It seem's, that it's not possible to linkt the two sources. Can anybody help me??

ERROR:

```
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/media/sf_Shared/Software/executables/TEST'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory '/media/sf_Shared/Software/executables/TEST/src'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I..    -Wall -Wno-psabi -w -pthread -I/usr/local/include -g -O2 -MT main.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/main.Tpo -c -o main.o main.cpp
mv -f .deps/main.Tpo .deps/main.Po
g++ -Wall -Wno-psabi -w -pthread -I/usr/local/include  -g -O2 -lmosquitto   -o TEST test.o main.o -lmosquitto 
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function `main':
/media/sf_Shared/Software/executables/TEST/src/main.cpp:564: undefined reference to `open_ports(unsigned int, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:366: TEST] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/sf_Shared/Software/executables/TEST/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:359: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/sf_Shared/Software/executables/TEST'
make: *** [Makefile:300: all] Error 2
```

I'm including in the main.cpp the test.h. There is the function open_ports declared(u_int32_t open_ports(u_int32_t a, u_int32_t b);), which is implemented in test.c

Comment: Quote the full error and show what call/function it applies to. Show how that function is declared and how it is called. Probably the mix of C/C++ linkage is tripping you up.

Comment: FYI, unrelated to the actual question: Adding `@LDFLAGS@` to a non-`_LDFLAGS` variable looks fishy. Add it to `_LDFLAGS` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an `automake` issue — you are doing the right thing (or at least close to) in the `Makefile.am`.

The problem is that your symbol is declared without `extern "C"`, but defined only in C, so when the C++ compiler takes your `main.cpp`, it expects to find a [mangled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling) symbols (which encodes the signature of the function, that is the number and types of parameters), rather than a plain (C) one.

You can tell that this is the case because it's looking for `open_ports(unsigned int, unsigned int)` — rather than just `open_ports`.

The easiest solution is to change your `main.cpp` to say:

```
extern "C" {
#include "test.h"
}
```

That declares that the `test.h` header only includes C declarations, which will then generate the right symbol lookup for what you define in `test.c`.

Comment: I would include the `extern "C" {` and `}` lines into the `test.h` file itself, but each wrapped into `#ifdef __cplusplus` and `#endif`. That way, you can then include `test.h` from any C and C++ file.

Comment: I think that's a contention point in the matter of style :) I prefer not mixing C++ constructs (`extern "C"`) in a C-only header, and instead being very aware of using "foreign language" (C) from C++.